# Feature, select suggested user in a comment-reply with up/down arrow. i.e. type `@SomeUs` suggested user popup `@SomeUser`, up arrow selects it

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

When composing comments, it is tedious to have to use the mouse to select the suggested user such as in the following image:

[image]

It would be really nice to be able to just push the up or down arrow and have it complete the user name as if it were just clicked.

System configuration:

- Mac OS 10.8.2
- Chrome Version 23.0.1271.101

Comment: Pressing tab works for me.

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware and I guess that would make this kinda unnecessary...

Comment: @BoPersson Indeed, this works. It feels unnatural, though.